# How do I stop syncing a folder outside ~/Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, directory, delete

Yes I know this question is in the FAQ but is no answear for them - I read it and don't find anything.

My problem is that I have a folder **~/linux** and I had synced that.

Then **My Folders** in "Ubuntu One Control Panel" is with 2 folders
- Ubuntu One
- linux

I dont want anymore sync linux.
How I exclude it from My Folders in "Ubuntu One Control Panel"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove it from the control panel at https://one.ubuntu.com (click the "Files" section).

Comment: Thank you very much Tohow. I proceed in this way and worked.

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Tohuw ! If any answer was helpful, could you please mark it as "Accepted" ? This would be really useful for people having the same problem in the future.

Comment: To clarify, @Rossano is actually the one who should mark this as accepted if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In the file manager (Nautilus) right click on your ~/linux folder, and choose the `Stop synchronizing` entry under the Ubuntu One menu.

Comment: In my case "stop syncronizing" was not available in Nautilus file manager. After that I created another folder to test syncronization and that works. I dont realize why but I had resolved this issue with https://one.ubuntu.com (Files" section). Thank you dobey!

Answer (score 1):

U have to remove it from the Ubuntu One web page on your account.U start Ubuntu One Control Panel and go to the 4th task Information about your account and then modify personal details online and the once U log in U cancel the folder and it's done.